# In SharePoint 2016, why would deleted documents go directly to the site collection recycle bin and not rest in the subsite's recycle bin?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2016, why would deleted documents go directly to the site collection recycle bin and not stop first in the subsite's recycle bin?

What are the settings to be checking that may affect recycle bin behavior?

Comment: is the document library on the site collection level or subsite level?

Answer (score 1):

Per my test in my SharePoint 2016 environment, then in the subsite, if I delete the document in the document library, the document will be in the site recycle bin. If I delete the document in the site recycle bin, the document will go to the site collection recycle bin.

If I delete the document in the site collection, then the document will go directly to the site collection recycle bin.

Where did you delete the document?

More reference:

[Manage the Recycle bin of a SharePoint site.](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/manage-the-recycle-bin-of-a-sharepoint-site-8a6c2198-910e-42dc-9a9c-bc5bc4f327da)